# Association severed exception when trying to delete a model with relationship

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-relationship, ef-core-3.1

Here are my models (abbreviated)

User:

```
public partial class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual BusinessOwner BusinessOwner { get; set; }
    //rest of code
}
```

and BusinessOwner, which has a foreign key to Users (User.Id = BusinessOwner.UserId)
meaning that a business owner has to be a user.

BusinessOwner:

```
 public partial class BusinessOwner
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    //rest of code
}
```

In a scenario, I have to delete a user, and so I got the user and included the relationship like this :

```
 public User GetByIdEager(int id)
    {
        return _context.User.Where(u => u.Id == id && u.DeletedAt == null)
            .Include(u => u.BusinessOwner)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

and here's my controller:

```
  public class UserController : ControllerBase
  {
      [HttpDelete("id")]
      public ActionResult Delete(int id)
      {
          User user = GetByIdEager(id);
          _context.User.Remove(user);
          _context.SaveChanges();
          return Ok();
      }
  }
```

I get the following exception when invoking  `_context.User.Remove(user);`

> The association between entity types Users and BusinessOwners has been
> severed but the relationship is either marked as 'Required' or is
> implicitly required because the foreign key is not nullable. If the
> dependent/child entity should be deleted when a required relationship
> is severed, then setup the relationship to use cascade deletes

even though I included BusinessOwner when I retrieved User. can someone tell me why this is happening? and how can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: alright, thanks for pointing that out. @Progman

Comment: have you set any mapping for these two tables?

Comment: No, I don't think I need any. and when I'm debugging and I click on User.BusinessOwner, I see that it is loaded successfully. why do I need mapping? @osmanRahimi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I know what's wrong, so I'm posting it in case anyone else had this problem too.

in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete)
, it turns out that there are multiple types of relationships : Cascade, ClientSetNull, SetNull and Restrict. and each one of these relationships has a delete behavior.

> At a high level:
>
> - If you have entities that cannot exist without a parent, and you want    EF to take care for deleting the children automatically, then
>   use    Cascade.
> - Entities that cannot exist without a parent usually make use    of    required relationships, for which Cascade is the default.
> - If you have entities that may or may not have a parent, and you want    EF to take care of nulling out the foreign key for you, then
>   use    ClientSetNull
> - Entities that can exist without a parent usually make    use of    optional relationships, for which ClientSetNull is the    default.
> - If you want the database to also try to propagate null values to    child foreign keys even when the child entity is not loaded, then use
>   SetNull. However, note that the database must support this, and
>   configuring the database like this can result in other restrictions,
>   which in practice often makes this option impractical. This is why
>   SetNull is not the default.
> - If you don't want EF Core to ever delete an entity automatically or    null out the foreign key automatically, then use Restrict. Note that
>   this requires that your code keep child entities and their foreign
>   key values in sync manually otherwise constraint exceptions will be
>   thrown.

And then I went to my DBContext and found that the relationship was automatically set to `ClientSetNull`, which is why I was getting the exception: the UserId field in BusinessOwner was set to NULL, and the table does not allow nulls in that field.
The solution was setting the delete behavior to `Cascade` instead of `ClientSetNull`. like this :
in my DbContext :

```
entity.HasOne(d => d.User)
                    .WithOne(p => p.BusinessOwner)
                    .HasForeignKey<BusinessOwner>(d => d.UserId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK__business___user___7E37BEF6");
```

and now whenever I delete a user, the business owner is deleted.